# AngularJS - When exactly is directive scope data first bound to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a general understanding of how AngularJS processes directives however I'm unsure of exactly when data for scope properties is being bound to a corresponding expression in the directive's HTML template. My understanding of directive processing (in simplified terms) is like this:

- AngularJs receives notification that the original DOM rendering is complete (i.e. the initial HTML sent to the browser has been parsed and the DOM is now initialised)
- AngularJS reads the DOM and 'gathers up' all AngularJS directives that it finds.
- Each directive is wrapped as an 'Angular element' and a 'compile' function is then executed on each directive. The compile function automatically receives the 'template element' as an argument. The 'template element' provides access to the original HTML template for the directive, including any expressions to be interpolated. The HTML of the template element might look like this :

  `<my-directive>`

  ```
      {{myProperty}}
  ```

  `</my-directive>`
- Any custom defined logic for 'compile' in the directive is then executed
- Following compilation, a 'link' function is returned, and it automatically receives the current scope as an argument.
- Any logic in the controller is executed.
- (If any pre-linking logic is defined in the directive it would then be carried out, but let's assume we're not doing this)
- The linking function is then automatically invoked - the purpose and meaning of 'link' is that it 'links' the scope with the template and it's at *this* point that watches are set up on the scope, including a watch for the value of `{{myProperty}}`
  (see 'How Directives are Compiled' in the official AngularJS docs - 
  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)
- Any post linking logic defined in the directive is then carried out (if we only have a 'link' function defined in our directive then it is executed as if it was 'post-link' logic i.e. the same as if we had defined a 'post:' function in our directive)
- The template is attached to the DOM

If we assume that the directive has isolate scope, where exactly in this process is `{{myProperty}}` in the template *first* substituted for the value of that property on the current scope, and how does AngularJS do this? Assuming my understanding of directive processing is correct, it looks like the initial subsitution is probably done just before the post-link logic is carried out - is this correct?

Comment: Within `$digest`.